# Create a mutlple email field input in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and would like to create an entry field where a user can enter multiple email address

So far, I have an email field

```
<TextValidator
     id="email"
     aria-label="email"
     label="Email address used to register"
     required
     name="email"
     value={this.state.email ? this.state.email : ""}
       onChange={this.handleChange({
                  name: "email",
                   index: 0
                 }).bind(this)}
                 autoComplete="email"
                 margin="normal"
                 variant="outlined"
                 fullWidth
                 validators={["required", "isEmail"]}
                 errorMessages={[
                    "this field is required",
                    "email is not valid"
                 ]}
  />
```

I would like either a way to enter multiple emails in the single field or maybe an add/remove button to do it.

This is want my input look like at the moment
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a typical `input` field... but a component of sorts. Is `<TextValidator />` something you created, or is it third party?

Comment: Can you try this https://codepen.io/antonietta/pres/RaYYvN

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-add-delete-items-on-input

Comment: @GBWDev.. I am using this package --https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-form-validator

Answer (score 0):

Try [React multi-email](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-email) - this is exactly what you're looking for.

Here's a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jpvjk8m5o9?file=/src/index.tsx) to the online demo where you can check it out.
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think to achieve that, you will need a stateVariable that holds the current text being entered by the user which you keep checking to see if its a valid email or alternatively check if the next key entered is a space and if so, add it to an array of existing emails.

To display the entered emails, you will need to use an editable div and a separate component that shows a single email, then loop through entered emails and display them as components inside the mail editable div

Something like

```
<EditableDiv>
  { email in emails
    <Email email >
  }
  <CurrentEntry {EmailBeingEntered} />
</EditableDiv>
```

The above ain't really react but just an overview of what it might look like

Answer (score 0):

A simple react component to format multiple email as the user types.

Simple code
No dependency
Small size
Simple customization

demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/jpvjk8m5o9

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-email